# Jquery focus not working initially in chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I am trying to set a webpage's focus to a text input on document ready like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#company_search").focus();
})
```

I have also tried to use setTimeout in the same manner:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $("#company_search").focus();
}, 5000);
```

But no matter what I do Chrome (desktop and mobile) will focus on the input initially and then lose focus in about a second. I can actually see it gain and lose focus, and I can even type in the text box while it has focus.

All other browsers work.

It does the same thing no matter what I focus on in the page (button, div, other inputs).

Perhaps even stranger, after I interact with the page (click a button, hide/show something) focus seems to work just fine. I can focus on anything and it stays focused.

Any ideas on what is going on? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code should work just fine as it is. Do you have any other code in the page? Or more than one element with the same ID (invalid markup)?

Comment: Yes, I have tried stripping all other javascript out. And have stripped out all javascript that isn't jquery. And have stripped out all css. Have tried different jquery versions too.

Comment: I figured it out. I had some iframes in my html, that are initially hidden, that didn't have a src attribute set yet. The src attribute gets set later. So the src attribute was defaulting to the current page in chrome. So there was more than one instance of every element in the dom.

Answer (score 0):

After getting dom ready then use setTimeout.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
setTimeout(function(){
    $("#company_search").focus();
}, 0);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I had some iframes in my html, that are initially hidden, that didn't have a src attribute set yet. The src attribute gets set later. So the src attribute was defaulting to the current page in chrome. So there was more than one instance of every element in the dom.